# Conditional types in TypeScript is not working

Tags: typescript

I was trying to implement Conditional types in TypeScript and, Am getting some weird errors.

Following is what, I have implemented:

```
declare function anyReturnType(x: TouchPoint | LocalizedResourceResponse | BusinessConfiguration | MessageResponse):
TouchPoint | LocalizedResourceResponse | BusinessConfiguration | MessageResponse;

type Returns = ReturnType<typeof anyReturnType>;
```

Above is the type we have defined.
Am trying to use the type as following:
runExclusive returns Observable.

```
getBusinessConfiguration(configurationName: string): Observable<BusinessConfiguration> {
    return this.runExclusive(
      'getBusinessConfiguration',
      configurationName,
    );
  }
```

Here, Type Script gives a compilation error saying,

*Type 'Observable<TouchPoint | LocalizedResourceResponse | BusinessConfiguration | MessageResponse>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
Type 'TouchPoint | LocalizedResourceResponse | BusinessConfiguration | MessageResponse' is not assignable to type 'BusinessConfiguration'.
Type 'TouchPoint' is missing the following properties from type 'BusinessConfiguration': entries, businessUnitId, retailSegmentId, namets(2322)*

Comment: Please provide a plaintext [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to get working on the problem. Right now you have a lot of undeclared types that are not available to others.  And `Observable` is not part of TypeScript; you should either define it, remove it, or tag the question with the appropriate framework (rxjs?) if the dependency is important to you.  I also don't see a conditional type in your question.  You have *unions*, which are not the same thing.  Please consider [edit]ing to rectify these issues.

Comment: Without detailed information, we cannot help. Please, provide all types definitions.